# Why do we choose the maximum value instead of minimum?

Tags: statistics, linear-programming, optimal-control, operations-research, optimal-transport

**Vogel's method selects the corresponding variable through a penalty**. There is a penalty for each row and column and is the subtraction between the two lowest costs (in absolute value).

**We must select the highest penalty** and then the lowest cost in the row or column of this penalty. I understand the second step (if you want to reduce the cost of the problem, you select the lowest cost of the row or the column), but not the first.

**I don't understand why we have to do the subtraction between the two lowest costs and, then, select the highest penalty**. Can someone tell me what the explanation is?

Answer (score 1):

It's a procedure.

We can choose minimum penalty also.